# Angular directive loses its style when bound to value inside ngFor

Tags: html, css, angular, angular2-directives

My directive is losing it's style when a value is passed to it dynamically inside a ngFor loop.

I have this directive for a datatable column, where I set the name of the column.

```
@Directive({ selector: '[my-dt-column]' })
export class MyDTColumn{
    @Output() onSort: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    @HostBinding('class.sorted-asc') sortedAsc;
    @HostBinding('class.sorted-desc') sortedDesc;
    _sortOrder: string;
    public sort(order?: string){
        this._sortOrder = order !== undefined ? order: (!this._sortOrder || this._sortOrder=='desc') ? 'asc' : 'desc'
        this.sortedAsc = this.sortOrder === 'asc';
        this.sortedDesc = this.sortOrder === 'desc';
    }
    get sortOrder(): string{
        return this._sortOrder;
    }
    get isSorted(): boolean{
        return this._sortOrder !== undefined && this._sortOrder !== null && this._sortOrder !== '';
    }
    column: string;
    @Input('my-dt-column')
    set setItem(column: any){
        this.column = column;

    }

    @HostListener('click') onClick(){
        this.sort();
        this.onSort.emit({orderBy:this.column, sortOrder:this._sortOrder});
    }

    constructor(private el: ElementRef){}
}
```

And some style for it, which basically sets the direction of an arrow-icon, indicating if the column is sorted or not, and its order.

```
:host >>>> table [my-dt-column]{
    cursor: pointer;
}
:host >>>> table  [my-dt-column] md-icon{
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    opacity: 0;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
    transition: transform .25s, opacity .25s;
    transform-origin: center center;
    text-align: center;
}
:host >>>> table [my-dt-column].sorted-asc,
:host >>>> table [my-dt-column].sorted-desc{
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}
:host >>>> table [my-dt-column].sorted-asc md-icon,
:host >>>> table [my-dt-column].sorted-desc md-icon{
    opacity: 1;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}
:host >>>> table [my-dt-column].sorted-asc md-icon{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
:host >>>> table [my-dt-column].sorted-desc md-icon{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
:host >>>> table [my-dt-column]:hover md-icon{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I was adding table headers with this directive manually in html, to something like this:

```
<th my-dt-column="ColumnName">some code</th>
<th my-dt-column="Column2Name">some code</th>
<th my-dt-column="Column3Name">some code</th>
<th my-dt-column="Column4Name">some code</th>
```

But in order to prevent typing errors, I decided to make an array in my parent component with the name of my columns, and added dynamically in html with ngFor.
So my code became something like this:

**Style over directive won't work, but the column's name is set.**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns">
   <th [my-dt-column]="column.name">some code</th>
</ng-container>
```

But suddenly my style over this directive stopped working. If I change the above code directive to some random string, my style will work, but the name of the column won't be correct.

**Style over directive work, but the column name is incorrect.**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns">
   <th my-dt-column="randomstring">some code</th>
</ng-container>
```

I couldn't find any answer for a problem like this, and any help would be nice.

**EDIT:**
1 more clue: when I bind a random string to this directive, it is set in my HTML(my-dt-column directive):

```
<th _ngcontent-c11="" mdtooltipposition="right" my-dt-column="randomstring" ng-reflect-position="right" ng-reflect-message="" ng-reflect-set-item="randomstring" class="">some code</th>
```

but when I try to pass the name of my column generated by ngFor, it won't set EVEN in HTML (note that in the example below, my-dt-column directive is missing.

```
<th _ngcontent-c11="" mdtooltipposition="right" ng-reflect-position="right" ng-reflect-message="" ng-reflect-set-item="InstrumentTypeName" class="">some code</th>
```

Comment: create a plunker to reproduce the issue

Comment: It will require a lot of time since i don't have any prattice with plunker. But i will try, altough my question is more to "why it work with a string, but won't work with a value passed?".Is it related to any delay from ngFor to provide the value in the loop, or something like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep attribute i can advice you use `@HostBinding` like

```
import { HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

....
column: string;
@HostBinding('attr.my-dt-column') @Input('my-dt-column')
set setItem(column: any){
    this.column = column;
}
get setItem() {
  return this.column
}
```

as you can see you also have to declare getter.

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/tbzEKxeMT9B2eOiKdDFN?p=preview)**

Another approach is using `host` property on your component

```
host: {
  '[attr.my-dt-column]': 'column'
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/co8f78P5ek3huTRKQ9kJ?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you! the hostbinding option worked! 
Also, another solution that i found was to change [my-dt-column] in css to .my-dt-column and add `host: {'[class]':'"my-dt-column"'}`. in the directive.